# How to correlate records between 2 history tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 5 tables (contrived and simplified for the question):

```
Device
---------------
DeviceID - INT IDENTITY - PRIMARY KEY
DeviceGUID - UNIQUEIDENTIFIER - UNIQUE CLUSTERED (used for lookups)
OtherInfo


Device_State
---------------
DeviceStateID - INT IDENTITY - PRIMARY KEY
DeviceID - INT - FOREIGN KEY - UNIQUE CLUSTERED (used for lookups)
Pump1 - TINYINT
Pump2 - TINYINT
Pump3 - TINYINT
Pump4 - TINYINT
Pump5 - TINYINT
Heater1 - TINYINT
Heater2 - TINYINT
Lights - BIT
TimeStamp - SMALLDATETIME

Device_State_History
---------------
DeviceStateHistoryID - INT IDENTITY - PRIMARY KEY
DeviceStateID - INT - FOREIGN KEY - NONCLUSTERED INDEX (used for lookups)
Pump1 - TINYINT
Pump2 - TINYINT
Pump3 - TINYINT
Pump4 - TINYINT
Pump5 - TINYINT
Heater1 - TINYINT
Heater2 - TINYINT
Lights - BIT
TimeStamp - SMALLDATETIME


Peripheral_State
----------------
PeripheralStateID - INT IDENTITY - PRIMARY KEY
DeviceID - INT - FOREIGN KEY - UNIQUE CLUSTERED (used for lookups)
Pump1 - TINYINT
Pump2 - TINYINT
PH - SMALLINT
ORP - SMALLINT
ELECTRODEID - TINYINT
ELECTRODEPOLARITY - TINYINT
TimeStamp - SMALLDATETIME


Peripheral_State_History
----------------
PeripheralStateHistoryID - INT IDENTITY - PRIMARY KEY
PeripheralStateID - INT - FOREIGN KEY - NONCLUSTERED INDEX (used for lookups)
Pump1 - TINYINT
Pump2 - TINYINT
PH - SMALLINT
ORP - SMALLINT
ELECTRODEID - TINYINT
ELECTRODEPOLARITY - TINYINT
TimeStamp - SMALLDATETIME
```

Here is the situation:

I have ~3.8 Million records in the Device_State_History table and I have ~100K records in the Peripheral_State_History table.

I would like to write a query that selects all of the Peripheral_State_history and Device_State_History for a given DeviceGUID between a give date-time. I would like to get records that have somthing like this:

```
Select 
 Peripheral_State_History.PH,
 Peripheral_State_History.ORP,
 ( 
 if(Device_State_History.Pump1 == 1 ||
    Device_State_History.Pump2 == 1 ||
    Device_State_History.Pump3 == 1 ||
    Device_State_History.Pump4 == 1 || 
    Device_State_History.Pump5 == 1
    ) 
    { 1 }
    else 
    { 0 }
  ) AS PumpsOn, 
    TimeStamp 
FROM CombinedData
```

Also, the TimeStamps between Device_State_History and Peripheral_State_History are not always the same. By this I mean that timestamps of records for 1 device in the Device_State_History table might be as such:

```
Mar-1-2013 12:31
Mar-1-2013 12:33
Mar-1-2013 12:36
Mar-1-2013 12:38
Mar-1-2013 12:41
```

And then there will be records in the Peripheral_State_History table:

```
Mar-1-2013 12:29
Mar-1-2013 12:33
Mar-1-2013 12:34
Mar-1-2013 12:38
Mar-1-2013 12:39
Mar-1-2013 12:41
```

As you can see, the timestamps do not always overlay.

I have been reading around and have taken a stab at writing a stored procedure to do this, however, this is beyond my SQL abilities, guidance and examples are really appreciated. Thank-you.

EDIT:

The following is a stored procedure I have written to get the data from the Peripheral_State_History table. It does not include the Pump data I want from the Device_State_History table.

A couple things to note: I am getting only 1 record per Time Stamp, as there are some Time Stamps with multiple records. This stored procedure grabs the current record out of the State table, as well as all the records out of the history table.

```
USE my_db
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'SP_Select_Stuff') 
DROP PROCEDURE 'SP_Select_Stuff') 
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE 'SP_Select_Stuff') 
( 
     @DeviceGUID uniqueidentifier
) 
AS
DECLARE @RetCode INT
;WITH combined AS
(
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
   (PARTITION BY [TimeStamp] ORDER BY [TimeStamp]) as num, ORP, PH, [TimeStamp] 
    FROM Peripheral_State
    INNER JOIN Device
        ON Peripheral_State.DeviceID = Device.DeviceID
        WHERE Device.DeviceGUID = @DeviceGUID 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
   (PARTITION BY [TimeStamp] ORDER BY [TimeStamp]) as num, ORP, PH, [TimeStamp]
    FROM Peripheral_State_History
    INNER JOIN Device
        ON Peripheral_State.DeviceID = Device.DeviceID
        WHERE Device.DeviceGUID = @DeviceGUID 

)
SELECT ORP, PH, [TimeStamp]
FROM combined
WHERE ORP > 0
AND PH > 0
AND combined.num = 1
ORDER BY [TimeStamp] ASC

IF @@ERROR <> 0
   BEGIN
        SET @RetCode = 5
        RETURN @RetCode
   END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @RetCode = 0
        RETURN @RetCode
    END
GO
```

EDIT:

Here is what I came up with.

```
USE my_db
--"combined" gets all of the data. 
--A row from the peripheral history will look like: ORP-Value, PH-Value, Current-Value, NULL, TimeStamp.
--A row from the device history will look like: NULL, NULL, NULL, PumpsOn-Value, TimeStamp
-- I also get a num for filtering 1 TimeStamp per minute. My TimeStamps are accurate to the minute, so if one minute has 30 records, I will use the first record.
;WITH combined AS
(   
    SELECT  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
   (PARTITION BY ph.[TimeStamp] ORDER BY ph.[TimeStamp]) as num, ph.ORP, ph.PH, ph.[Current], NULL as PumpsOn, ph.[TimeStamp] 
    FROM Device as d

    LEFT JOIN Peripheral_State as ps
    ON ps.DeviceID = d.DeviceID

        LEFT JOIN Peripheral_State_History as ph
        ON ph.DeviceID = d.DeviceID

        WHERE d.DeviceGUID = @DeviceGUID
        AND ph.TimeStamp BETWEEN '2013-03-02 00:00:00' AND GETDATE() 

    UNION ALL   

    SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
   (PARTITION BY dh.[TimeStamp] ORDER BY dh.[TimeStamp]) as num, NULL as ORP, NULL as PH, NULL as [Current], IsNull(COALESCE(dh.Pump1, dh.Pump2, dh.Pump3, dh.Pump4, dh.Pump5),0) as PumpsOn, dh.[TimeStamp]
    FROM Device as d

    LEFT JOIN Device_State as ds
    ON ds.DeviceID = d.DeviceID

       LEFT JOIN Device_State_History as dh
       ON dh.DeviceID = d.DeviceID

        WHERE d.DeviceGUID = @DeviceGUID
        AND ph.TimeStamp BETWEEN '2013-03-02 00:00:00' AND GETDATE()            
),
--"FilteredAndAddID" gets a record set that has an ID added to the row. This is required for the 3rd step.
--It also filters the data so that records with 0 orp/ph are omitted.
FilteredAndAddID AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [TimeStamp]) as ID,
        ORP,
        PH,
        [Current],
        PumpsOn,
        [TimeStamp]
    FROM combined
    WHERE 
    (ORP is NULL OR ORP > 0) AND (PH is NULL OR PH > 0)
    AND combined.num = 1
),
--"filled" is used to fill the "FilteredAddID" record set NULLS with the previous row that has a value instead of NULL.
filled AS
(
    SELECT  Curr.ID,
            ISNULL(Curr.ORP, (SELECT TOP 1 ORP FROM FilteredAddID WHERE ID < Curr.ID AND ORP IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID)) ORP,
            ISNULL(Curr.PH, (SELECT TOP 1 PH FROM FilteredAddID WHERE ID < Curr.ID AND PH IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID)) PH,
            ISNULL(Curr.[Current], (SELECT TOP 1 [Current] FROM FilteredAddID WHERE ID < Curr.ID AND [Current] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID)) [Current],
            ISNULL(Curr.PumpsOn, (SELECT TOP 1 PumpsOn FROM FilteredAddID WHERE ID < Curr.ID AND PumpsOn IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID)) PumpsOn, 
            Curr.[TimeStamp]
    FROM    FilteredAddID Curr
)
SELECT ID, ORP, PH, [Current], PumpsOn, [TimeStamp]
FROM filled
ORDER BY [TimeStamp] ASC
```

The first 2 queries "combined" and "FilterAndAddID" execute in miliseconds, however the "filled" query takes roughly 6 minutes to fill the nulls in ~1700 records.

Is there anyway to speed this up?

Am I approaching this the right way?

Ideally I need this to run in seconds.

Comment: Can you add to your post above the structure of Peripheral_State_History?

Comment: It is in the code block, you have to scroll. I will try to fix this.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?  What is your tolerance for vaguely matched date/times?

Comment: @HABO I added, the current stored procedure I have written. Please see my edit. This does not get a comparison to the records in the Device_State_History table. This is where I am stuck. I am not sure how to pull in the pump information I am looking for in my post.

Comment: @Mausimo - Do you know what the correct output should look like in any particular case? Are you clear on the requirements?

Comment: @HABO as long as the date-times are within ~5-10 minutes, that would be fine. Also, one thing that I can do is look at the previous record in the Device_State_History table to determine what happen in the time span between the 2 records (thought I do not know how to do this). If the first record shows Pump1 is 1 and the next records shows Pump1 is 0, then I can say that Pump 1 was set to 1 between the 2 records.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, I would like to get records of data from the 2 history tables as per my pseudo select statement in the original post. If you look at my edit, it includes a stored procedure I have written. It includes the PH, ORP and TimeStamp from the Peripheral_State_History but not the data from the Device_State_History table.

Comment: @Mausimo, as i understand, you have two pairs of tables with same state data: Device_State is pair of Device_State_History and Peripheral_State is pair of Peripheral_State_History. The count of rows is the same in paired tables, because without record in *_state table, you can not say what device associated with record in *_history table. Am I right?

Comment: @shibormot The Device_State table holds the last state record for a device. Where as the Device_State_history table has a record added everytime the Device_State table record is inserted or updated. If the database has 10 devices, the Device_State table holds 10 records, it is a one-to-one relationship to the number of devices. However, the Device_State_History table is a one-to-many relationship to the Device_State table on DeviceStateID and will continuously grow as Device_State records are updated.

Comment: @shibormot I can retrieve all the Device_State_History records and Peripheral_State_History records for a particular device. However, the time-stamps are not the same, and the frequency of records are not the same in the history tables. For example, the Device_State_History might have 10 times the records as the Peripheral_State_History. Also, lets say I get a record from Peripheral_State_History with a time stamp of Mar 2 2013, 10:30AM, The Device_State_History might not have a record with that time stamp, it might have a record with Mar 2 2013, 10:29AM and Mar 2 2013, 10:33AM.

Comment: @Mausimo you need result where exists exactly one row for each row from Peripheral_State_History and PumpOn is from last Device_State_History before Peripheral.timestamp? or where one row for each row from Device_State_History?

Comment: @shibormot I would like to get "where exists exactly one row for each row from Peripheral_State_History and PumpOn is from last Device_State_History before Peripheral.timestamp".

Comment: @Mausimo CTE's are still just subquerys and they will get executed for every row. While `combined` and `FilterAndAddID` might only take milliseconds for a single run those milliseconds can still add up to minutes if you have to execute them 100.000 times or more. Try to add them in temp tables and tell me what the execution time is then. I know some people say it doesn't matter if you use temp tables, but I've fixed several stored procedure from 3+ minutes to less than 10 seconds by just doing that.

Comment: @JodyT Thanks for the input. I am not sure how to use temp tables. I will have to look it up. Or if you could provide an example, that would be great!

Comment: Seems like you got a good solution from @shibormot already, still, here is a [very simplified example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac1cc) of using temp tables.

Comment: @JodyT Yea, his example is working good. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long run this query?

```
;with combined as
(
select
   psh.PH, psh.ORP, psh.TimeStamp, 
   max(dsh.TimeStamp) as Device_Stamp
from Peripheral_State_History psh
  join Peripheral_State ps on ps.PeripheralStateID = psh.PeripheralStateID 
  join Device d on d.DeviceID = ps.DeviceID
  left join Device_State ds on ds.DeviceID = d.DeviceID
  left join Device_State_History dsh on dsh.DeviceStateID = ds.DeviceStateID 
    and dsh.TimeStamp <= psh.TimeStamp
where d.DeviceGUID = @DeviceGUID
  and psh.TimeStamp between @date1 and @date2
group by psh.PH, psh.ORP, psh.TimeStamp
)
select 
  c.PH, c.ORP, c.TimeStamp, 
  case 
    when dsh.Pump1 = 1 and dsh.Pump2 = 1 and dsh.Pump3 = 1 
      and dsh.Pump4 = 1 and dsh.Pump5 = 1
    then 1 else 0 end as PumpsOn
from combined c
  left join Device_State_History dsh on dsh.TimeStamp = c.Device_Stamp
  left join Device_State ds on ds.DeviceStateID = dsh.DeviceStateID
  left join Device d on ds.DeviceID = d.DeviceID
where d.DeviceGUID = @DeviceGUID
```

**EDIT**

Addressing problem with multiple records with same timestamp in Device_State_History.

If you have for greater DeviceStateHistoryID always greater or equal timestamp then you can try this query. It chooses one record with max DeviceStateHistoryID where records have same timestamp in Device_State_History

```
;with combined as
(
select
   psh.PH, psh.ORP, psh.TimeStamp, 
   max(dsh.DeviceStateHistoryID) as DeviceStateHistoryID
from Peripheral_State_History psh
  join Peripheral_State ps on ps.PeripheralStateID = psh.PeripheralStateID 
  join Device d on d.DeviceID = ps.DeviceID
  left join Device_State ds on ds.DeviceID = d.DeviceID
  left join Device_State_History dsh on dsh.DeviceStateID = ds.DeviceStateID 
    and dsh.TimeStamp <= psh.TimeStamp
where d.DeviceGUID = @DeviceGUID
  and psh.TimeStamp between @date1 and @date2
group by psh.PH, psh.ORP, psh.TimeStamp
)
select 
  c.PH, c.ORP, c.TimeStamp, 
  case 
    when dsh.Pump1 = 1 and dsh.Pump2 = 1 and dsh.Pump3 = 1 
      and dsh.Pump4 = 1 and dsh.Pump5 = 1
    then 1 else 0 end as PumpsOn
from combined c
  left join Device_State_History dsh on dsh.DeviceStateHistoryID = c.DeviceStateHistoryID
  left join Device_State ds on ds.DeviceStateID = dsh.DeviceStateID
  left join Device d on ds.DeviceID = d.DeviceID
where d.DeviceGUID = @DeviceGUID
```

Comment: Trying this right now. It is executing in 8-9 seconds and returning 10K records. I just need to verify the data is correct and understand everything you have written. I will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: This is fantastic, just by understanding what you have done, I have gained a lot! I should be able to modify/write other queries based on this example. Thank-you, this is a great query. Since I receive many records per minute, I really only want to know 1 record per minute. Previously I was using ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY table.[TimeStamp] ORDER BY table.[TimeStamp]) as num and where num = 1. Is this what I should be using to do this? (p.s you get the bounty, it just says I need to wait 1 hour).

Comment: @Mausimo, you are welcome) again i don't understand clearly to answer your question) If you need only first row with lowest timestamp, why not just `select top 1 ... from sometable order by timestamp`?

Comment: the Device_State_History table has 3-4 records per timestamp because they are accurate to the minute. For example, Peripheral_State_History table might have only 1 record for 2013-03-04 20:17:00, but the Device_State_History table will have 3 records with timestamp 20:17:00. I would like to only get 1 record per timestamp.

Comment: Is there anyways to do something like: from combined c
  left join Device_State_History dsh on dsh.TimeStamp = TOP 1 c.Device_Stamp ?

Comment: @Mausimo, in Device_State_History you have multiple records with same timestamp? but values of other columns are the same or not (Pump1 etc)? if not how to decide wich record needed? If the same you can use `select distinct ...` instead of last select

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have multiple records with the same timestamp in Device_State_History. Values of the other columns (pump 1 etc) are different so I can not use select distinct. I would just like the first record for the timestamp, regardless of pump values. Thank-you for your continued help :).